# how to calculate the HOGDescriptor for specified locations in opencv

Tags: visual-c++

I am trying to find HOG descriptor for human activity recognition, how to find the HOG descriptor for the specified location using opencv

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is no inbuilt functionality for that. You should extract area yourself and give it as a "Mat" type for hog.compute() method.

hint: study OpenCV "hog.detectMultiScale" method which does similar kind of thing.